# HTML - changing color in text area from an option inside of a select box generated from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have been trying to search for things similar to what I want but can't seem to get the exact solution. I am in no way a HTML coder, but I have to do some work in HTML, so I am learning. I understand that my code is probably a bit messy/unneeded, so please forgive me. I have managed to find some similar javascript so you will see this below.

- First I have a table created with select boxes and text areas inserted into the cells.
- The select boxes are generated from MySQL (so am using PHP also).
- When I select a specific option from that select box, I want my text area background to change, in a different cell.
- I have given the text area's an ID so that this can be made possible.

I currently can use this:

```
<select  onChange="updateColor(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"  name="sunday combo" id="Suncombo2">
    <option value= " " selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="FFFFCC">light yellow
    <option value="CCFFFF">light blue
    <option value="CCFFCC">light green
    <option value="CCCCCC">gray
    <option value="FFFFFF">white'
```

```
    Javascript: 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function updateColor(color){
    var myCell = document.getElementById('2ndInputSun');     
        myCell.style.background = "#"+color;

}
```

HTML:

```
<tr class="5row">
<td class="2ndInputMon"><textarea></textarea></td>
<td class="2ndInputTues"><textarea></textarea></td>
<td class="2ndInputWed"><textarea></textarea></td>
<td class="2ndInputThurs"><textarea></textarea></td>
<td class="2ndInputFri"><textarea></textarea></td>
<td class="2ndInputSat"><textarea></textarea></td>
<td class="2ndInputSun"><textarea></textarea></td>
```

However, when I insert all this, I get no change in colour from the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given the elements an ID you have given them a CLASS. so getElementById() will not work. Change the html to add the ID not the CLASS.

Comment: Brilliant... haha thanks. However, is there a way to change the text area colour too?

Comment: Yes use jQuery. It is so much easier to traverse the DOM than with basic js functions. Not that you should not learn raw javascript, indeed you must.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have no experience with jQuery though. Could you explain how I would be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateColor(color){
 myCell = document.getElementById('2ndInputSun');     
        myCell.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "#"+color;

}
```

This will change color of textarea (firstChild of td).

Also, you can simplify this:  `onchange="updateColor(this.value);`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hrybcahk/

Comment: Thanks, that's great! As I already described though, the text area is inside of a table, so ideally I would like to change the colour of the whole cell, including text area simultaneously, is this possible?
EDIT: Actually, I guess I would use the two bits of code together?

Comment: Yes,  myCell.style.backgroundColor = "#"+color; and myCell.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "#"+color;

Comment: Thanks all working now. Thanks for you're help. Was going to add your answer as "answered", but it was not from the original question.