# HTML - using mysql/php to generate a select box. how can I change the "value" of the generated select box options?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So my select box is generated from mysql (php), this means that I am unable to insert a "value" (as far as I know) like this:

```
<option value="CCFFFF">light blue
```

My select box is generated like this:

```
?php 
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
  {
    echo '<select  onChange="updateColor(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"  name="sunday combo" id="Suncombo2">
    <option value= " " selected="selected">Please Select</option>';
    while ($test = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$test['am_task'].'">'.$test['am_task'].'</option>';
  }
    echo '</select>';   
  }
  ?>
```

The reason for using the "value" is so that I am able to automatically change the colour of the selected option from the select box. 
Is there a way I can do this? 
I have two options:

- holiday
- TBC

These are defined inside of the MySQL and I know they're not going away. So I would like "holiday" green, and then "TBC" orange. Any other value generated from the select box I would like blue. Is this possible, not sure if I am well out of my depth or not?

I already have the code for changing the colour which is located inside of here: [HTML - changing color in text area from an option inside of a select box generated from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399075/html-changing-color-in-text-area-from-an-option-inside-of-a-select-box-generat/29399226#29399226)

Comment: I really don't see what your problem is. Please tell me why you cannot change the value to whatever you want? <sarcasm>Keyboard not working?</sarcasm>

Comment: Use two different fields from the db, one for the value, one for the display name.....that's assuming I've guessed what you're getting at.

Comment: KIKO... looking for some help, not a troll... But the reason for this is because if I change the option value, it will be the same value for each generated input. So I am looking over 10 values here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a filed in your sql tabe naming "color" then you sql would be like this:

```
select color,am_task from mytable
```

and when printing options:

```
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($test['color']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($test['am_task']).'</option>';
```

Comment: Note that `htmlspecialchars` is a good idea here, in case the color/task contain quotation marks, `<` signs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different fields from the db, one for the value, one for the display name:

```
echo '<option value="'.$test['am_color'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($test['am_task'], ENT_QUOTES).'</option>';
```

I'm going to assume you don't have this field yet, so obviously you need to add it, using something like (unless you have a GUI for editing table schemas):

```
alter table am_dropdown add am_color varchar(20);
```

Then update the records to pair your color with the task name:

```
update am_dropdown set am_color='green' where am_task='holiday';
```

Comment: I used your example, so I added in the extra "am_color" and assigned each colour to the variable I needed.
Now I am looking at using: $result =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM am_task WHERE am_color = 'green'") or die (mysql_error()); 
and then:        echo '<option value="'.$test['am_color'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($test['am_task'], ENT_QUOTES).'</option>';  
I want to do this for the green, blue and orange though, and cannot combine the 3 to have the, green, orange and blue values in the same select box.

Comment: @Tom just take out the where clause and you'll get them all. When you're building the dropdown why would you limit it to one row like `WHERE am_color = 'green'`?

Comment: @Tom there's also `in()`: `WHERE am_color in('green', 'blue')`

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works. But the whole reason I am wanting this is so that I can then set a "value", so I would use something like "value='blue'" (this would show all values just in blue, with in the value blue), so that with my HTML table and select box, I would select a blue entry in the select box, and then it would change the text field blue. I want the same with green, and the same with orange. Thanks